# MapState not found Vuex4 with Vue3 in MVC project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, es6-modules, vuejs3

In my MVC project i am using Vue3 with Vuex4 and they are working but i have got one issue with mapState.

if I use these import statements i am getting this error:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
```

**1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

So i add these files in my _Layout page to fix it

```
<script src="~/lib/vue/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/vuex/vuex.global.js"></script>
```

So far it is working. But when i want to use mapState, i am stack! not sure how to fix it,

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
```

I searched for mapStaate.js file but couldn't find or the files i find has just few lines of code and not working...

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    count: 0
   }
})

const homeIndex = {
data() {
    return {
    }
},
computed: mapState({
    count: state => state.count,
  })
}

Vue.createApp(homeIndex).mount("#app");
```

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI?

Comment: Hi Dan, no i don't use Vue CLI, It is not single page application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` statement is for modules.  You don't need the module syntax since you are loading the scripts directly.  Remove the `import` statement and use `Vuex.mapState` like you used `Vuex.Store`:

```js
computed: Vuex.mapState({
   count: state => state.count,
})
```

If you prefer, you can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to give a similar appearance to imports.  Then you could use `mapState` as you did in the question:

```js
const { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } = Vuex;

computed: mapState({
   count: state => state.count,
})
```